# Using values from two tables to run query in Hive

Tags: hive

I would like to run a hive query to be able to divide a column from one table by the total sum of a column from another table.
Do I have to join the tables?

The code below generates errors:

```
Select 100*(Num_files/total_Num_files) from jvros_p2, jvros_p3;
```

> FAILED: Parse Error: line 1:75 mismatched input ',' expecting EOF near 'jvros_p2'

Yes, jvros_p3 is a single row single column table

Num_files is a column in jvros_p2 and total_Num_files is a single value in jvros_p3.

Comment: Which version of Hive are you running?  I was able to run your query with no error on Hive 0.13.0.  Note: I defined a table named `jvros_p2` with a single column named `num_files` and populated it with three rows containing arbitrary integers, and also defined a table named `jvros_p3` with a single column (and single row) also with an arbitrary integer.

Comment: I believe its an old version 0.7.1
I cant yet upgrade due to other work restrictions

Comment: I've not had a chance to get a minimal installation of 0.7.1 installed to test, but I think the solution may be to explicitly specify the `JOIN` instead of the comma-separated implicit join notation (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

Your older version may be why your notation isn't working.  Try this:

```
SELECT 100 * (Num_files / total_Num_files) FROM jvros_p2 JOIN jvros_p3;
```

I suspect that if you are eventually able to upgrade to at least 0.13, implicit join notation via comma-separated tables will be supported per [HIVE-5558](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5558).

Comment: thanks @rchang for your replies and help. but still no luck here
Select 100*(Num_files/total_Num_files) from jvros_p2 join jvros_p3;
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.NullPointerException(null)
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genJoinReduceSinkChild(SemanticAnalyzer.java:4443)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genJoinOperator(SemanticAnalyzer.java:4548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticAnalyzer.genJoinPlan(SemanticAnalyzer.java:4707)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.Semanti.....

Comment: @Javad Sorry it didn't work.  I guess my best suggestion at this point is to upgrade when you can.  :)  Good luck.